# Is <a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">Go back</a> safe?

Tags: javascript, php, hyperlink, href

I have a link like the one in the title in a **custom 404 error page**, which allows the user to go to the previous page just like with the browser's go back button. I just wanna ask if this method of linking is safe or not. I guess it is safe, but I am not sure. Thanks in regards!

Comment: Define `safe`, please.

Comment: One can imagine site impersonation for very inattentive users. But rather than a security danger it mostly looks like a bad idea on a UI point. The browser already has this feature.

Comment: It will just go back 1 step in browser history. The only thing that is not ok is if someone got to your website from another page (eg: Google) it will go back to google.

Comment: So why are you bringing yourself some extrawork.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to find out how to get the URL from where the user came from, I tried the $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] but it didn't work, so I found that solution, which worked. So there are no security problem except that this is not the best solution, am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One use case I can say that will not be "safe" is if the user has JavaScript disabled. In that case, you would have to create the link dynamically with server-side code using the [HTTP `referer` header field's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer) value as your `href` value on the anchor element.

Another thing to consider is the never-ending back and forth loop users would get stuck in, if they came from a page with an HTTP redirect.

**Edit**:

As you said above, you can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` but the documentation says

> .. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this,
> and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In
> short, it cannot really be trusted.

In reality, most browsers do set it correctly though, and seeing how this is not mission critical I think it's safe if you use it. You could also account for browsers that don't set it as follows:

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']))
{
    // Show a Back button link, if the referrer is available
    echo "<a href=\"".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."\">&laquo; Back</a>";
}
else
{
    // If not, show a link to your homepage instead
    echo "<a href=\"". "//www.yoursite.com" ."\">Home</a>";
}
```

Comment: How can I do this via server-side?

Comment: Without tracking their movement, you can't.

Comment: I mean, create the link dinamically? For example with php?

Comment: @user3019105 Updated the answer with more info and a PHP example

Comment: the HTTP_REFERER is set by the browser so here is why you controlled if the variable is set right?

Comment: @user3019105 Correct.